# Metz 48 AF1 incorrect exposure on Pentax K3ii

Tags: flash, pentax, metz

My Dad recently upgraded his Pentax K5 to a K3ii. He has a Metz 48 AF1 flash which worked perfectly on the K5, and also on my sister's Kx.

On the K3ii it wasn't exposing properly at all. It seemed to be always firing at full power, often resulting in over exposure.

We have found what appears to be a solution, but I wanted to document it, see below for my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metz 48 AF1 has USB updatable firmware. The latest version was released about the same time as the Pentax K5ii, so it doesn't mention the K3 bodies in it's release notes. But we thought it was worth a try.

A quick firmware update on the flash later and it's now working perfectly with the K3ii.